# Clang static analyzer warning "Null pointer argument in call to CFRelease"

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, memory-management, clang-static-analyzer

In Xcode 4.6, the clang static analyzer warns me about a "Null pointer argument in call to CFRelease".

Here's a screenshot of the analyzer warning:

[image: Clang Static Analyzer Warning]

And here's the code in case you want to copy & paste it:

```
- (void)test
{
    CFUUIDRef aUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    [self setUUID:aUUID];
    CFRelease(aUUID);
}

- (void)setUUID:(CFUUIDRef)uuid
{
    _uuid = uuid ? CFRetain(uuid) : CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
}
```

I don't understand why it is warning me. `aUUID` can never be a null pointer, can it? I've learnt to rather mistrust myself than the tools I'm using, so I'm asking here. I would be very glad if someone explained to me what I'm missing.

Comment: `CFUUIDCreate()` might return `NULL` in case the allocation fails, but the logic of the analyzer warning is wrong. `aUUID` isn't changed in `-setUUID:`, so no matter where `uuid` is null or not, `aUUID` can still be null.

Answer (score 0):

Anything returning an allocated value could, in theory, return NULL.

The analyzer follows multiple possible paths of execution. While following the "aUUID is NULL" scenario, it eventually ends up at the CFRelease of the NULL object.

It's not that `setUUID` is the cause, that's just the path along which the issue was spotted, so that's the path that's illustrated.